# How to tell if a new scripture is authentic, according to scripture?

Tags: scripture, puranas

The dating for the Purāṇas is not given in scripture, meaning one could easily conclude they are still being composed to account for language changes, changes in theme, etc.

Anyway, say a new scripture appeared one day, how would one know it was true or not? If it is complicated enough, you might be able to determine a mortal human did not write it, but what about a malevolent supernatural force? Does the scripture ever address this issue and tell you how to spot a real new scripture from a false one e.g. a list of features a true scripture must have?

Comment: Know any example of new scripture?

Comment: @Proxy No, but there is no reason one could not appear one day.